# rsync --config from stdin

Tags: rsync

Attempting some rsyncs with the following template on the destination:

```
rsync --daemon --port=7000 --config=$REALLY_SIMPLE_FILE
```

and then running this on the src:

```
rsync -aHPv --port=7000 /some/directory dst::$CONFIG_NAME
```

is it possible to make rsync read the configuration file(on the dst) from stdin? or to pass it as some sort of string such that i dont have to actually write a file?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because when running `rsync` as a daemon, it will fork a new process for every connection and every such process will read the config file again. In other words, even if the file is passed on STDIN and read by the parent process, the first child will have nothing to read.

Verify it yourself.

```
$ rsync --daemon --port=7000 --config=simplefile
$ cat simplefile
[test1]
path=.
...
$ rsync  rsync://localhost:7000/
test1           
$ sed -i -e s/test1/test2/ simplefile
$ cat simplefile
[test2]
path=.
$ rsync  rsync://localhost:7000/
test2
```

You could make a named pipe and have a process write the config to it in a loop, but this is just as bad and arguably writing a file or writing to a fifo is the same thing.